# Extending the Core Form BaseType in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm looking to extend the form BaseType, and this is what I have so have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class BaseTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public static function getExtendedTypes() : iterable
    {
        return [BaseType::class];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'icon' => null
        ]);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {

        $view->vars['icon'] = $options['icon'];
    }
}

?>
```

The issue with this is when I created a form with the `icon` option, it returns the `The option "icon" does not exist` error.

The thing is, the extension is registering, if I use `php bin/console debug:form` it shows that the extension is there like so:

### Type extensions

- App\Form\Extension\BaseTypeExtension

What is missing here?

Comment: genuine curiosity, why do you extend basetype and not abstracttype? comment in basetype says: "This type does not appear in the form's type inheritance chain and as such cannot be extended (via {@link \Symfony\Component\Form\FormExtensionInterface}) nor themed."

Comment: Ok, that actually makes sense. So does that mean I just do "AbstractType" and itll resolve it?

Comment: It's so hard to find that info, makes sense, thanks for sharing. Maybe you can add that to the an answer and I can give it a shot @Jakumi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseType cannot be extended as pointed out from @Jakumi's answer, although you shouldn't extend AbstractType either, if you're looking to effect the form builder. Instead, you should extend `FormType` which is the base to any of the inputs as stated [here.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html)

So to sum up, this is what my `FormTypeExtension` outlines:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public static function getExtendedTypes() : iterable
    {
        return [FormType::class];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'icon' => null
        ]);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {

        $view->vars['icon'] = $options['icon'];
    }
}

?>
```

It worked, now I can use the extension of "icon" within my form builder inputs.

Answer (score 1):

(**update** for those whom it may concern: this answer isn't correct, apparently)

As far as I can tell, all form types usually extend `AbstractType` and not `BaseType`. I actually don't know, what `BaseType` is for, but probably for some specific forms.

So you should write an extension for `AbstractType` instead, since everything extends `AbstractType`. As an example form type extension (possibly to be confused with form extension):

[TransformationFailureExtension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TransformationFailureExtension.php)

which also is an extension for `AbstractType`.

on top of that, with the `BaseType` there is a comment in the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d4e6a37b1475b08c46db7fad9feb97826b3fef22/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/BaseType.php#L23):

> This type does not appear in the form's type inheritance chain and as such cannot be extended (via {@link \Symfony\Component\Form\FormExtensionInterface}) nor themed.

Comment: That didn't work, I did some digging though and I got a solution

Comment: @Majo0od mh ... good find. Interestingly enough, FormType extends BaseType (which extends AbstractType), but none of the other built-in form types appears to extend either BaseType nor FormType. However, the `createForm` call may ultimately produce a FormType though...? I don't know tbh. but it all seems weird and badly documented ...

Comment: You’re not wrong. It’s super hard to find these specific details unless you spend time diving into each individual source file lol.